# Second Stiefel-Whitney class is a square

Tags: cohomology, examples, characteristic-classes, stiefel-whitney

I'm interested in examples of manifolds which are orientable and such that the second Stiefel-Whitney class is a square. (Of course the second Stiefel-Whitney class should be non-zero.)

An easy example is the real projective space $RP^n$ in the case $n \equiv 1 \ (\operatorname{mod} 4)$. But unfortunately, I don't know any more examples. I know that for $2$- and $3$-manifolds have the nice property $\omega_2 = \omega_1^2$, but it implies that orientable $2$- and $3$-manifolds have always vanishing second Stiefel-Whitney class.

If we know $\omega_2 = x^2$, we can apply $\operatorname{Sq^1}$ to it to get $\operatorname{Sq^1}(\omega_2) = 0$. On the other hand, using Wu's formula and since we assume $\omega_1 = 0$, we get $\operatorname{Sq^1}(\omega_2) = \omega_3$. So this means that I'm especially looking for orientable manifolds with vanishing third Stiefel-Whitney class ... what does this condition mean geometrically?

Comment: What has got you interested in this question?

Comment: We are currently trying to get obstructions against positive scalar curvature metrics on (totally) non-spin manifolds. We can get a nice obstruction under the condition in the question, and so now we are looking for examples where we might apply our theorem. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At least there are quite a lot of such manifolds: up to multiplying by powers of 2, any oriented bordism class contains such a manifold.

Proof: Let $f: X \to BSO$ be the universal map such that $w_2$ pulled back to $X$ is a square of a class $x$.  I.e. $X$ is the fiber of a map $w_2 - x^2: BSO \times K(\mathbb{F}_2,1) \to K(\mathbb{F}_2,2)$.  Then there is a Thom spectrum $Mf$ and a map of bordism groups $\pi_d(Mf) \to \pi_d(MSO)$ which becomes an isomorphism  after inverting 2.  If $d \geq 4$ and $M$ is some oriented manifold, then there exists an $n \gg 0$ such that $2^n [M] \in \pi_d(MSO)$ lifts to $\pi_d(Mf)$, i.e. there is an oriented bordism from the disjoint union of $2^n$ copies of $M$ to a manifold $N$ such that $\tau N: N \to BSO$ admits a lift to a map $N \to X$.  If $d \geq 5$ (and maybe 4?), there is no obstruction to doing surgery on $N$ in order to make the map $N \to X$ 2-connected, and hence $H^2(X;\mathbb{F}_2) \to H^2(N;\mathbb{F}_2)$ is injective so $w_2$ stays a non-zero square in $N$.  $\square$

If you like, we can partially control the homotopy type of the manifold.  For example, if $d \geq 4$ and we write $n = \lfloor d/2\rfloor$ we could use surgery to make the map $N \to X$ $n$-connected.  More generally, given an $n$-dimensional finite $CW$-complex $X'$ there is only the "obvious" homotopical obstruction to $X'$ being an $n$-skeleton for a manifold with the requested property: if there exists a map $f: X' \to BSO$ with $f^*(w_2) \in H^2(X';\mathbb{F}_2)$ a non-zero square, then there exists an $n$-connected map from $X'$ to a manifold with the requested property.

Answer (score 9):

First note that the collection of orientable manifolds with $0 \neq w_2(M) = x^2$ for some $x \in H^1(M; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ is closed under products. Moreover, given two such manifolds of the same dimension, their connected sum is another; this is because the Stiefel-Whitney classes of a connected sum are the 'sum' of the Stiefel-Whitney classes of the summands (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2062853/39599)) and $x^2 + y^2 = (x + y)^2$. In addition, given such a manifold, taking a product or connected sum with a spin manifold also provides another such manifold

As $\mathbb{RP}^5$ is an example, the constructions mentioned above provide infinitely many examples in each dimension greater than or equal to five. In dimension four, we would also obtain infinitely many examples **if** we could find a four-dimensional example, but that is yet to be demonstrated. So the interesting question now becomes:

> Does there exist an orientable four-manifold $M$ with $0 \neq w_2(M) = x^2$ for some $x \in H^1(M; \mathbb{Z}_2)$?

**Added later:** As is shown in [this note](http://cirget.math.uqam.ca/%7Ealbanese/notes/grass_spin.pdf),  if $m \equiv n \bmod 4$, then $w_2(\operatorname{Gr}(m, m + n)) = w_1(\gamma)^2$ which is non-zero except when $m = n = 1$; here $\gamma$ denotes the tautological bundle. As is also shown in the previous link (alternatively, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/666282/39599)), the grassmannian $\operatorname{Gr}(m, m + n)$ is orientable if and only if $m + n$ is even. The condition $m \equiv n \bmod 4$ implies $m + n$ is even, so the manifolds $\operatorname{Gr}(m, m + n)$ with $m \equiv n \bmod 4$, except $\operatorname{Gr}(1, 2) = \mathbb{RP}^1 = S^1$, are also examples. In particular, setting $m = 1$, we recover the examples $\mathbb{RP}^n$ with $n \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, $n > 1$.

This observation also provides an explicit four-dimensional example, namely $\operatorname{Gr}(2, 4)$.

Comment: for what concern your last question, I believe the answer is yes, even though I'm unable to provide explicit examples. Looking at almost spin 4-manifolds, one can define the so called $w$-type of it, which basically is the preimage via the classifying map $c_* : H^2(\pi_1M;\mathbb{Z}_2)\to H^2(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ of $w_2(M)$ (this definition involves a Serre SS argument). Then one can compute the stable diffeomorphism classes of orientable manifolds with $w$-type $x^2$ and in some examples it turns out that the class is not empty, which means that exists the 4-manifold with the required property